# Correct way of making a polymorphic ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have a `User` model and a `Dispute` model. A dispute contains a list of involved users, as well as an "accuser" and a "defendant". I want to be able to do this:

```
Dispute.first.users
#[<User 1>, <User 2>]

Dispute.first.accuser
#<User 1>

Dispute.first.defendant
#<User 2>
```

So here's my models:

```
class Dispute < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :accuser,    polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :defendant,  polymorphic: true
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :disputes

  has_one :user, as: :accuser
  has_one :user, as: :defendant
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateDisputes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :disputes do |t|
      t.references :accuser, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.references :defendant, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This gives me the behavior I want except that `Dispute.new.save` errors out unless I assign a user to `dispute.accuser` and `dispute.defendant`.

It also looks wrong: Shouldn't a user **have** one dispute **as** an accuser/defendant? I can't seem to get it to work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest something simpler? I hope I got it right.

Models:

```
class Dispute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accuser,    class_name: 'user'
  belongs_to :defendant,  class_name: 'user'
  
  def users
    [accuser, defendant]
  end 

end

class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateDisputes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :disputes do |t|
      t.references :accuser, index: true, references: :user
      t.references :defendant, index: true, references: :user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey that works and makes more sense, thanks. There's still a problem with the `Dispute` not saving unless both accuser and defendant fields are present. ("Accuser must exist" and "Defendant must exist" errors). I'd like to understand why that is

Comment: `belongs_to :accuser, optional: true`
`belongs_to :defendant, optional: true`